# how to get the bottom of a layout in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-relativelayout, android

I'm using a relative layout in Android, and when adding a view to the bottom of the screen the view is placed lower than the actual bottom of the screen, where the user cant actualy see it.

```
view.setY(container.getBottom()-view.getHeight());
container.addView(view);
```

container is a RelativeLayout. i have also tried to use container.getHeight() which gave me the same result, and all the other solutions i found where using the xml file, which doesnt work for me since i need to add the view dynamically in a random position above the bottom of the screen, meaning

```
view.setY(container.getHeight()-Common.random.nextFloat()*100-view.getHieght());
```

this is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    tools:context="il.co.ovalley.dashvsponypolice.app.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the View im trying to add:

```
public class GameView extends ImageView{
  public GameView(RelativeLayout container) {
      super(container.getContext());
      m_container=container;
      container.addView(this);
  }
}

public class Cop extends GameView {
  public Cop(RelativeLayout container) {
    super(container);
    m_isShooting=false;
    m_LoadingTime=10;
    m_isLoading=false;
    m_xSpeed=1.5f;
    setY(container.getHeight()-Common.random.nextFloat()*100-getHeight()/*-getPaddingBottom()*/);
    float x=(Common.random.nextFloat()*m_container.getWidth());
    setX(x);
    drwableState=0;
    changeDirection();
 }
```

I have tested that on different versions of android and screen sizes and got the same result. so far, the only solution I found was subtracting an arbitrary int from the container's height which seems ok on one device and hope for the best for the others, I'm sure there is a better solution.

thnx

Comment: Does your Relative Layout has a fixed height?

Comment: nope. match_parent, and the is the root view

Comment: As per Xaver answer, Try to set the view as parent bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just place the view at the bottom of the screen with `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` and then apply a random padding?

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, randomValue);  // left, top, right, bottom

container.addView(view, params);
```

All this calculating with the `view.getHeight()` is not good. Doing it like this works without you having to manage any of that yourself.

Comment: Why are you being so dismissive? If this didn't work then there is a problem with the layout itself and not with the position of the views in the layout. Please edit the complete layout xml into your question.

Comment: updated. not much in the xml though, i also added details of the view im trying to add. sorry for sounding dismissive, I wasnt trying to be. and thanks again

Comment: Hmm I think it is an issue with your custom views but it is difficult to say as I couldn't reproduce the error you are getting, it works perfectly for me. I replaced the calls to `setX()` and `setY()` with the solution I posted above and I assigned the padding and rules from outside of the custom view. You should not have a view position itself somewhere inside the layout. That may be the source of the error as well.